When solving eigenvalues, what does the factor in front of the Root[] mean?
I tried to solve the eigenvalue of a matrix like this:
Eigenvalues[{{0, 0, A Exp[i*a], 0, C, D Exp[-i*a]}, {0, 0, 0, 
   A Exp[-i*a], D Exp[i*a], C}, {A Exp[-i*a], 0, M, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
   A Exp[i*a], 0, M, 0, 0}, {C, D Exp[-i*a], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D Exp[i*a],
    C, 0, 0, 0, 0}}]

The matrix looks like this:
$M=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}0 & 0 & A e^{i a} & 0 & C & D e^{-i a} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & A e^{-i a} & D e^{i a} & C \\ A e^{-i a} & 0 & M & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A e^{i a} & 0 & M & 0 & 0 \\ C & D e^{-i a} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ D e^{i a} & C & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$
When I solved it, the solution is:
{E^(-a i) Root[C^2 E^(3 a i) M + 2 C D E^(3 a i) M + D^2 E^(3 a i)M + (-A^2 E^(2 a i) - C^2 E^(2 a i) - 2 C D E^(2 a i) - D^2 E^(2 a i)) #1 - E^(a i) M #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
 E^(-a i) Root[C^2 E^(3 a i) M + 2 C D E^(3 a i) M + D^2 E^(3 a i)M + (-A^2 E^(2 a i) - C^2 E^(2 a i) - 2 C D E^(2 a i) - D^2 E^(2 a i)) #1 - E^(a i) M #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
 E^(-a i) Root[C^2 E^(3 a i) M + 2 C D E^(3 a i) M + D^2 E^(3 a i)M + (-A^2 E^(2 a i) - C^2 E^(2 a i) - 2 C D E^(2 a i) - D^2 E^(2 a i)) #1 - E^(a i) M #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3], 
 E^(-a i) Root[C^2 E^(3 a i) M - 2 C D E^(3 a i) M + D^2 E^(3 a i)M + (-A^2 E^(2 a i) - C^2 E^(2 a i) + 2 C D E^(2 a i) - D^2 E^(2 a i)) #1 - E^(a i) M #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
 E^(-a i) Root[C^2 E^(3 a i) M - 2 C D E^(3 a i) M + D^2 E^(3 a i)M + (-A^2 E^(2 a i) - C^2 E^(2 a i) + 2 C D E^(2 a i) - D^2 E^(2 a i)) #1 - E^(a i) M #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
 E^(-a i) Root[C^2 E^(3 a i) M - 2 C D E^(3 a i) M + D^2 E^(3 a i)M + (-A^2 E^(2 a i) - C^2 E^(2 a i) + 2 C D E^(2 a i) - D^2 E^(2 a i)) #1 - E^(a i) M #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}

What does the E^(2 a i) in front of Root[...] mean? Does it mean I multiply all the roots by this value to get the eigenvalue?

As @Goofy in the answer below points out, it is more interesting how solving the characteristic polynomial gave a differnet result than the Eigenvalue[] function.

To address the comment from @A. Kato, I did try to change the i to I and it was giving the same results. So I didn't think it was the issue of the imaginary $i$. 

(1) C, D are protect system symbols with built-in usages; they shouldn't be used as variables/parameters. Generally avoid capitals. (2) OTOH, capital I is the imaginary unit. Did you mean that instead of i? (3) The answer to the question is yes.

Your question very interesting in the following sense: the parameter independence of eigenvalues is easily detected, but the result of Eigenvalues[ ] does not reflect this fact.

@Goofy, you are absolutely right, sorry for being sloppy with my symbols

You are right. But, it turns out that all the eigenvalues of this particular matrix are independent of the value of a. To see this, let us first compute the characteristic polynomial:
ClearAll["Global`*"]
matrix={
{0,0,A Exp[i*a],0,C,D Exp[-i*a]},
{0,0,0,A Exp[-i*a],D Exp[i*a],C},
{A Exp[-i*a],0,M,0,0,0},
{0,A Exp[i*a],0,M,0,0},
{C,D Exp[-i*a],0,0,0,0},
{D Exp[i*a],C,0,0,0,0}};

charpoly = Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[matrix, T], T, Expand]


Therefore, the eigenvalues are given by
Solve[charpoly == 0, T]



The set of eigenvalues is also independent of the value of i. :) Of course, the individual expressions returned by Eigenvalues[] are not, which is interesting.

@Goofy You are completely right! I thought i is the imaginary unit (as it should be), not the parameter :-)

@Goofy Thank you for your answer! I actually tried to solve the characteristic polynomial and got the same result. I was wondering why the two calculations are different but now I look at it, they should probably produce the same final results after solving the cubic equation there. But your method seems to be superior. I wonder why Mathematica doesn't use similar way to solve the Eigenvalues like you did.

@A.Kato I was being sloppy with syntax there but I belive Mathematica still recognized my i as the imaginary I here.

@OrionPax No, no. Mathematica always regard lower case "i" different from the imaginary unit. As Goofy pointed out, all the eigenvalues are independent of both "i" and "a". Whatever values are assigned to these parameters, the answer remains the same. You can of course assign Sqrt[-1] to the variable "i".   :-)

@A.Kato that's weird, because I tried to change all my $i$'s to $I$'s and I got the same resutlt, see the modified question for the screenshot.
